# Android Emulator Display Issue

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

My Android emulator is having render issues like in the image. When i restart the emulator or switch to another screen it becomes normal but if I don't interact with it for a while the issue pops up again.

I tried changing the AVD Manager settings to Software GLES but the issue still persists.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z8KsJ.png)

Comment: Something similar started to happen to me few months ago. It worked fine, but suddenly it started to show views like this. I solved it with update of windows. I suppose that some windows update introduced this bug in my case.

Comment: That's interesting. I'll see if I have any pending updates. Thank you